# INSERT node into PHP AST with nikic/PHP-Parser

Tags: php, php-parser

Im using https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser. What is a good strategy when wanting to INSERT a node in the AST? With the traverser I can UPDATE and DELETE nodes easily using a `NodeTraverser` class. But how can I "INSERT before" or "INSERT after" a node?

Example: When traversing an AST namespace I want to INSERT a `Use` statement just before the first non-use statement.

I started working with `beforeTraverse` and `afterTraverse` to find indexes of arrays but it seems overly complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose you need `enterNode` and check it's type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to replace one node with multiple nodes. This only works inside leaveNode and only if the parent structure is an array.

```
public function leaveNode(Node $node) {
    if ($node instanceof Node\Stmt\Return_ && $node->expr !== null) {
        // Convert "return foo();" into "$retval = foo(); return $retval;"
        $var = new Node\Expr\Variable('retval');
        return [
            new Node\Stmt\Expression(new Node\Expr\Assign($var, $node->expr)),
            new Node\Stmt\Return_($var),
        ];
    }
}
```

See last section in [Modyfing the AST](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/doc/component/Walking_the_AST.markdown#modifying-the-ast)

Comment: Insufficient in my case. I need to add a `use` statement in the namespace, but ONLY IF the alias will actually be used in the class defined later inside that same `Namespace_` node. At the moment of `leave()`ing the `Use_` node, I haven't even begun visiting the `Class_` node and determining whether I will be making changes to it that will make use of the class I might want to `Use_`. So I must record that information in the visitor, and apply it when leaving the `Namespace_` node.